# stock price history with zoom in/zoom out

Tags: stocks

Does anyone know a stock history source which provides zoom in/zoom out? I want to see the minutes-level history of a stock. But, all the places I can find right now do not provide minutes-level details. I am also using E-trade and Interactive Brokers. But, I also cannot find the minutes-level details. Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charting feature of the Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation offers you the ability to select the bar size.  You have a variety of choices with the shortest being one minute.  I don't recall the cut off point due to chart space limitations but at a minimum, you can see all of today's one minute bars.  It defaults to a longer time length if you load more days.

On the granular level, you can see every trade (with size) as well the changing bid/ask (with size) you go into Time & Sales but that's data rather than charting.

Comment: I just checked Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation. If I am correct, you can only see the minute-level data for the recent days. You cannot see the minute-level data for older days. For example, I cannot see the minute-level data for last Aug. 1st.

Comment: You are correct.   Take a look at Barcharts.com  It allows you to zoom in on previous time periods as well as select the time period for the bars.

Comment: This works. Barcharts.com allows me to choose date range and show the price by minutes. Thanks